# Bound ComboBox not matching

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# but not to programming. I've been toying around with VS, becoming more comfortable with the language and got stuck on a combobox bound to an int datatable column of an in-memory dataset.

I worked on a **DataGridView** and had no problems creating a **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** and populating its dropdown list using a custom class comprised of `Key:int` and `Desc:string`. `ValueMember = Key`, `DisplayMember = Desc`. **DataSource** is left as null since the list is directly built into the ComboBox.  Pick from the combobox and save changes works fine in the grid.

Then I moved to a **ComboBox**.  Both the grid and the ComboBox have the exact same BindingSource. So yes they point to the same row at the same time.

I bind the ComboBox with:

```
cbCtrl.DataBindings.Add( "Text", myBindingSource, ColDBName );
```

Without populating the dropdown items of the ComboBox, I see the raw int value show up in the ComboBox.  I change rows using the grid and the ComboBox value changes too.  So it's good.

Then I populate the dropdown list of items in the ComboBox (the same as the grid's column tied to the same column) and it's trouble.  The raw int value (eg 19) does not get matched to the proper "Key" item in the dropdown list of the ComboBox.  I've tried **DropDownStyle = DropDown** & **DropDownList** but no luck with either.  And I've looked for hours trying to find a fix.  There are no events hooked up to the ComboBox.  I expected automatic hookup of the raw value to the matching "Key" item in the ComboBox's dropdown list.

Is there something else to hook up?  Frustrating since I expect something minor.

Any help would be Greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*Edit: The dropdown list actually comes from a populated **BindingList<>** and the **BindingList<>** is supplied as the **ComboBox.DataSource**.

Answer (score 0):

I finally stumbled upon the answer:

cbCtrl.DataBindings.Add( "SelectedValue", myBindingSource, ColDBName );

That's all I needed. I got it from a great article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial?msg=5325959#xx5325959xx